# Detecting whitespace in Java String regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, whitespace

I am testing a postcode which should begin with two letters ('U' and 'S'), followed by up to two numbers. This works find but my problem is detecting any white space that may follow this. I do not want to permit any whitespace after these have been input. I have used the following code:

```
              while(!(postcode.matches("([U][S])([0-9]{1,2})+!(\\s)"))){
```

The above code seems to allow any white spaces after the permitted string. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `matches()`, there is no need to explicitly check that there are no spaces. If there is something following the number(s) it will not match.

You can simplify your expression a bit though. Just do:

```
while(!(postcode.matches("US[0-9]{1,2}"))) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Anchor it with a $ at the end of the regex may work:

```
while(!(postcode.matches("([U][S])([0-9]{1,2})+$"))){
```

Comment: The `$` anchor does nothing when you use `matches()` here.

Comment: Rightly so.  I just checked the API.  Thanks!